# Unable to access the headers of an API response in python

Tags: python, python-requests

So I want to access the response headers of an API, initially I was doing

```
requests.post(url, json = {"":""})
```

but it was giving SSL certificate error, so I changed the code to

```
requests.post(url, json = {"":""}, verify=False)
```

Now I'm able to get the response, but the headers have gotten modified. Earlier there were 16 parameters in the header and I wanted to access one of them. But after the verify=False thing, there are only 4 parameters in the headers and the parameter I want to access(Authorization) is not there.[image: this is the earlier header, i want to access the Authorization parameter]

[image: but after the verify=False, it is not there.]

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom headers on your post request, with dictionary to the `headers` parameter.

```py
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
 
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

[Source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python)

Comment: No actually I'm calling another api internally, I want the header from that api. I don't want to set my own headers.